# why doesn't this code work on jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, maps, jsfiddle

ok here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vh79z/2/

and here is a working example:
http://jvectormap.com/examples/france-elections/

Simple question.. It works on the example page, and I think I have replicate it perfectly - but it does not work.

I am trying to implement this code into my own project and trying to work from this example - but it is useless since I can't get it work.

please help

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('http://jvectormap.com/data/france-elections.json', function (data) {
    new jvm.WorldMap({
        map: 'fr_merc_en',
        container: $('#map2007'),
        series: {
            regions: [{
                scale: {
                    '1': '#4169E1',
                        '2': '#FF69B4'
                },
                attribute: 'fill',
                values: data['year2007'].results
            }]
        }
    });

    new jvm.WorldMap({
        map: 'fr_merc_en',
        container: $('#map2012'),
        series: {
            regions: [{
                scale: {
                    '1': '#FF69B4',
                        '2': '#4169E1'
                },
                attribute: 'fill',
                values: data['year2012'].results
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is with your getJSON and CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing).

Basically, the browser won't let you perform an XHR request to data from another domain - so it's throwing an error. If you open your developer console window, you'll see an error that looks something like

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://jvectormap.com/data/france-elections.json. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

This is a security features of browsers to prevent certain kinds of attacks. In order for this to work properly, the server over at jsvectormap needs to send out a special header in their response that indicates to the browser that it is safe to load data from their domain into the domain you're executing from. There's really nothing you can do about it on your end, unless the person you're grabbing data from also supports JSONP (a way of circumventing the requirement of CORS headers).

Can you try grabbing the data you want first and just pasting it into JSFiddle directly as a JavaScript object?

EDIT:

Doing that, it seems like it works great. Here's the code (I would post a JSFiddle, but I can't have more than two links in a post with this little reputation):

```
$(function(){
    var data = {"year2012":{"candidate1":"Hollande","candidate2":"Sarkozy","results":{"FR-J":1,"FR-G":2,"FR-S":1,"FR-Q":1,"FR-F":2,"FR-P":1,"FR-D":1,"FR-O":1,"FR-M":2,"FR-A":2,"FR-I":2,"FR-R":1,"FR-E":1,"FR-T":1,"FR-B":1,"FR-N":1,"FR-L":1,"FR-V":2,"FR-C":1,"FR-K":1,"FR-U":2,"FR-H":2,"FR-GP":1,"FR-MQ":1,"FR-GF":1,"FR-YT":2}},"year2007":{"candidate1":"Sarkozy","candidate2":"Royal","results":{"FR-J":1,"FR-G":1,"FR-S":1,"FR-Q":1,"FR-F":1,"FR-P":1,"FR-D":1,"FR-O":1,"FR-M":1,"FR-A":1,"FR-I":1,"FR-R":1,"FR-E":2,"FR-T":2,"FR-B":2,"FR-N":2,"FR-L":2,"FR-V":1,"FR-C":2,"FR-K":1,"FR-U":1,"FR-H":1,"FR-GP":2,"FR-MQ":2,"FR-GF":1,"FR-YT":2}}};

    new jvm.WorldMap({
      map: 'fr_merc_en',
      container: $('#map2007'),
      series: {
        regions: [{
          scale: {
            '1': '#4169E1',
            '2': '#FF69B4'
          },
          attribute: 'fill',
          values: data['year2007'].results
        }]
      }
    });

    new jvm.WorldMap({
      map: 'fr_merc_en',
      container: $('#map2012'),
      series: {
        regions: [{
          scale: {
            '1': '#FF69B4',
            '2': '#4169E1'
          },
          attribute: 'fill',
          values: data['year2012'].results
        }]
      }
    });
});
```

exmple HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/Vh79z/3/

Comment: Yes I could, but I don't know how to do that -as I am a newbie :) The file looks like this :{"year2012":{"candidate1":"Hollande","candidate2":"Sarkozy","results":{"FR-J":1,"FR-G":2,"FR-S":1,"FR-Q":1,"FR-F":2,"FR-P":1,"FR-D":1,"FR-O":1,"FR-M":2,"FR-A":2,"FR-I":2,"FR-R":1,"FR-E":1,"FR-T":1,"FR-B":1,"FR-N":1,"FR-L":1,"FR-V":2,"FR-C":1,"FR-K":1,"FR-U":2,"FR-H":2,"FR-GP":1,"FR-MQ":1,"FR-GF":1,"FR-YT":2}},"year2007":{"candidate1":"Sarkozy","candidate2":"Royal","results":{"FR-J":1,"FR-G":1,"FR-S":1,"FR-C":2,"FR-K":1,"FR-U":1,"FR-H":1,"FR-GP":2,"FR-MQ":2,"FR-GF":1,"FR-YT":2}}}

Comment: Refresh this page :) I've updated my answer with complete code and a more detailed explanation of CORS. Good luck!

Comment: Don't forget to accept and/or upvote an answer if it helped you out at all! If you have any other issues with my answer, just let me know here in the comments :)

Comment: I would upvote, but I don't have enough reputation :) but it did help me out :) thank you very much!!